# Rename-Item, convert date format

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have a problem with convert date format in file name.
Is there a way to rename a file using

```
Dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name }
```

To convert

```
dd.mm.yyyyy_string.txt
```

to

```
yyyyy.mm.dd_string.txt
```

Or rename files in a directory in another way with powershell

Comment: Assuming the year in the from date has only 4 places I edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish your task,

here is one which relies on the given structure

```
dd.mm.yyyyy_string.txt
```

and uses the `.split()` method to cut the BaseName into pieces,

reorders them and combines them with the string format operator.

```
Get-ChilItem ??.??.????_*.txt -File | 
  Rename-Item -NewName {("{0}.{1}.{2}_{3}" -f $_.BaseName.split('._',4)[2,1,0,3])+$_.extension} -WhatIf
```

This works even with the above string and not just digits in the date.
Reformatted sample output (German locale):

```
WhatIf: Ausführen des Vorgangs "Datei umbenennen" für das 
Ziel "Element: A:\dd.mm.yyyy_string.txt  
Ziel:          A:\yyyy.mm.dd_string.txt".
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`

To better restrict to actual dates insert a `Where-Object`

```
Get-ChilItem ??.??.????_*.txt -File | 
  Where-Object BaseName -match '^[0-3][0-9]\.[01][0-9]\.\d{4}_' |
    Rename-Item -NewName {("{0}.{1}.{2}_{3}" -f $_.BaseName.split('._',4)[2,1,0,3])+$_.extension} -WhatIf
```